# Socket read() doesn't block after second call on it

Tags: java, sockets

This is my Socket test program. 
My problem is that when I execute the code below. After I call read() on Socket InputStream for first time, it block as expected. 
But when loop go back to read() again, it never blocks on read() again? Thus it ends up with a tight and endless loop.

What should I do if I want to use separate thread to get server response? Is there any design pattern for this requirements?

```
package test.socket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestMario {

  private InputStream in;
  private OutputStream out;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new TestMario().go();
  }

  public TestMario() {

    try {
      Socket echoSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 1234);
      in = echoSocket.getInputStream();
      out = echoSocket.getOutputStream();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void go() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Thread writer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
        String userInput;
        try {
          System.out.print("input your command:");
          while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("you type:" + userInput);
            writer.print(userInput);
            writer.flush();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    });

    Thread reader = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

      public void run() {

        while (true) {
          System.out.println("waiting for server response...");
          try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            byte[] content = new byte[512];  
            int bytesRead = -1;  
            while((bytesRead = in.read(content)) != -1) { // read() doesn't block anymore after first read
              baos.write(content, 0, bytesRead);  
            } // while
            System.out.println("got:" + new String(baos.toByteArray())); 
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }

    });

    writer.start();
    reader.start();

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it doesn't block?

Comment: Can we see the server?

Comment: It might be that the program is regularly getting data from the sender..And the loop reading from socket continues working as it is not blocking..

Comment: @assylias, yes, I debug it, it always return -1 after first successfully read.

Comment: @EJP, It only blocks for first time I call read(). Because it continuously print my system out log, so I can make sure it didn't block on read().

Comment: @Djon, sorry, server is out of reach for me. I just call someone's server.

Answer (score 3):

This means that it either returns -1 or throws `IOException`. You implemented 2 loops: the internal loop verifies that value returned by read and exits if value is -1. This is fine. However the outer loop `while(true)` makes you to enter the read again and again, so it is not blocked anymore because the end of stream is achieved.

EDIT: credits to  @assylias that wrote comment that hints this.

Comment: +1 for end of stream reached with no exit condition for outer loop

Comment: @AlexR, thanks for response. It did always return -1 after first successful read, if any exception occurred, I should see exception stack printed. If I go out of "while" loop whenever -1, how should I maintain a active connection in order to receive server push message? Any advice? thanks a lot.